# question in proof of maximal function bound

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f^*(x):=\sup_{x \in B}\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B \vert f(y) \vert dy$

In proving $m(\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: f^*(x)>\alpha\})\leq \frac{3^d}{\alpha}\vert \vert f \vert \vert_{L^1}$ In Stein $\&$ Shakarchi, the proof has a part where he fixes a compact subset of $E_\alpha:=\{x:f^*(x)>\alpha\}$ and saying since the inequality holds for a compact set, that it is enough. I cannot see why he's allowed to fix a compact set out of nowhere and say since it holds for arbitrary compact sets that it works in general.

Comment: Because Lebesgue measure is a regular measure.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith thanks!!!!